# What are the conditions in a smart contract of an ICO

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ico

my question may be wrong, hope people understand i basically want to know what do people mean by "smart contracts" for ICO

Answer (score 1):

A smart contract is a piece of code executed in the Ethereum network. For the ICO the smart contract basically runs code that allows it to receive ether and return tokens. For more than this general answer, you will be better off just googling "smart contract".

Some basics [here](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/smart-contracts/).